# How can I parse this json with a model in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to parse this json with a model, but i don't know how, can someone help me please?

```
{
    "onboarding" : [
        {
            "image" : "assetsblablabla",
            "title" : "Your favorite delivery",
            "subtitle" : "We got over 200 afiliated commerces for you"
        },
        {
            "image" : "assets sdidj",
            "title" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "texto_2" : ":0"
        },
        {
            "image" : "assets/uwu/owo",
            "title" : "Service on demand",
            "subtitle" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Go to [here](https://app.quicktype.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your model as ("TestModel" is the arbitrary name I have used),

```
class TestModel {
  var onboarding;

  TestModel.fromJson(Map json) {
    this.onboarding = json['onboarding'];
  }
}
```

Then parse it as,

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var json = {
      "onboarding": [
        {
          "image": "assetsblablabla",
          "title": "Your favorite delivery",
          "subtitle": "We got over 200 afiliated commerces for you"
        },
        {
          "image": "assets sdidj",
          "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
          "texto_2": ":0"
        },
        {
          "image": "assets/uwu/owo",
          "title": "Service on demand",
          "subtitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
        }
      ]
    };
    var fromTheModel = new TestModel.fromJson(json);
    return Text(fromTheModel.onboarding[0]['image']); //displays "assetsblablabla" 
  }
```

The last line is obviously an example. You can replace the index `[0]` as well as the `['image']` according to your specific cases.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: i'm not sure, i need to parse that json to use the information in a pagebuilder.

Comment: I believe you can use the `fromTheModel` variable in your requirement. This is the parsing part that you asked in the original question.